# Can anyone explain what is happening in "sed-regex here"

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm practising sed command using regex but the results are not as expected. I'm using terminal on mac Sierra.
This is the input data:

```
Mark watermellons 12
Robert pears 4
Terry oranges 9
Lisa peaches 7
Susy oranges 12
Mark grapes 39
Anne mangoes 7
Greg pineapples 3
Oliver rockmellons 2
Betty limes 14
```

I'm trying to swap first and second column. I used this command:

```
sed 's/\(.+\) \(.+\) /\2 \1/ ' file.txt
```

This command is returning the same input. However when I use,

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) /\2 \1 /' file.txt
```

the columns are getting swapped. why "+" is not matching since atleast one  character is present in each row.

Also,
when I use

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1 /' file.txt
```

The first parenthesis is capturing first two columns and second one last column,why the first parenthesis is not capturing first column?

Comment: Because the `+` quantifier isn't available by default. sed uses the BRE syntax. With BRE `+` is only a literal character.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so it's grabbing as much as possible to still satisfy the regex before allowing the second `.*` to match anything.

Comment: The space after the second capture group is forcing the first capture group to only match the first word, since that's the only way for the regex to capture to word groups and have two whitespaces in it. By removing the second whitespace, the third example allows it to match the one specified whitespace against the last one in the input due to the greedy `/*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not about your understanding of regular expressions and greedy matching and whatnot. The problem is simply that the `+` is not implemented in the example uses in the question.

In `sed`, *by default*, `+` does not mean "one or more of the previous symbol" as you might be used to it from other regex grammars.
To make this work in BSD `sed` (as you are on OSX),
you need to enable extended regular expressions with `-E`,
and also change the capturing group syntax:

```
sed -E 's/(.+) (.+) /\2 \1/ ' file.txt
```

Also note that `+` is basically just a shortcut,
so you can always write it the good old-fashioned way:

```
sed 's/\(..*\) \(..*\) /\2 \1/' file.txt
```

Btw, always beware of the difference between BSD `sed` and GNU `sed`.
For example this works as expected in GNU `sed` but not in BSD `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.\+\) \(.\+\) /\2 \1/ ' file.txt
```

The first two solutions in this post work in both GNU and BSD `sed`.
Whenever possible, it's good to prefer syntax that will work in both,
to prevent all sorts of debugging hell.

Answer (score 3):

Casimir et Hippolyte noted in the comment that `+` isn't available in sed.

`s/\(.*\) \(.*\) /\2 \1 /` says "Match 0 or more characters followed by a space, followed by 0 or more characters, followed by a space. So to match, the input string must have at least 2 whitespace characters with any number of other characters, but it **must have at least 2 spaces**.

`s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1 /` says "Match 0 or more characters followed by a space, followed by 0 or more characters. So to match, the input string must have **at least 1 space** and any number of other characters. Since `.*` is greedy, it's matching the first column, first space, and second column, and then the space portion of the pattern matches the second space of the input, and the last `.*` evaluates to 0 characters.

Comment: @Sundeep, argh, you're absolutely right. I misread the output when I tried it and thought it worked, but it didn't. I shall edit.